# To use LoaderManager for detail view or not?

Tags: android

I'm building a (master-detail) view that has 2 fragments: a
ListFragment and a more detailed Fragment view.  Clicking on any item
in the list reveals a Detail View. For the ListFragment, I'm using a
LoaderManager with a CursorLoader, to manage my queries (I've been
following the excellent guidelines in Alex Lockwood's posts on the
subject).

When it comes to revealing the "detail" view (by clicking on the list
view), I need to query the same content provider, and get a single row of
information. I'm unsure as to how best to handle this.

Since I'm essentially getting back a single row, and can free the cursor right away:

- Should I just use a straight getContentResolver().query() and work with a cursor directly?
- Use another LoaderManager to manage the cursor and results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LoaderManager.

The same reason you are creating the Loader in your List view is the same reason you should create it in the Details View. Any heavy operations should be placed on a background thread to prevent UI unresponsiveness. Database interactions are no exception to that rule. It  may seem like your data loads instantly but in reality you're doing some heavy work directly on the UI thread which can give unwanted performance in your UI

Project butter, yo

Plus, you get the added benefits of the LoaderManager retaining your results. So, when you rotate and reload the data it is loading a cached result instead of you having to retain all of the data yourself.

Comment: Thanks - I like the fact that the LoaderManager stores results - a definite bonus. However, since this pattern essentially uses the ContentProvider as a caching data store, the fetches should be quick. That's why I am a bit torn as to whether it might be overkill to do anything more than a direct query.

Comment: @roymath I wouldn't consider preventing UI slowdowns overkill. You may consider 100ms to be a trivial amount of time but in Google's mind that's an unacceptable length of time to pause the UI. Additionally, if your data in your provider changes for your Details item while viewing it, the CursorLoader (provided you have your content providers configured correctly) will automatically reload your data without any additional coding by you.

Comment: How does one use a loader for a detail view? There's not any `AdapterView` implementations for a single item.